# Passing money through a different account to avoid cash pay-in fees

Tags: united-kingdom, fees, cash

I have recently sold some company assets (not a large figure) and the buyer insisted on paying cash.

My question is, my BUSINESS bank charge 0.6% on cash deposits, which is annoying - In theory, is there anything wrong with paying the cash into my personal account (I am the sole director of the company) and then doing a bank transfer (which they do not charge for) of that amount direct to the company account? as long as this is documented, is there any reason I shouldn't?

Both accounts are in my name, and with the same bank (HSBC, UK).

(This is a hypothetical question really, I will almost definitely just deposit the cash direct to the account)
I Know I COULD just hold the cash, and use it for bills etc, but then there is an accounting gap that would need to be addressed.

Comment: If you asking about laws, you really need to indicate the locale. Countries, states, etc - all have different rules and laws.

Comment: Good point - amended

Comment: When you say "both accounts are in my name", do you mean that the business one has your name as the holder, and not the business name?

Comment: It is in the company name, but my name is on the only debit card, and all correspondence is in my name (all statements etc) I set the account up.

Comment: You pay cash into the account, will be counted as income. In you accounts you add the amount for assets disposed. The 0.6% charge can be deducted as business expense(not 100% sure but ask your accountant). I also have a debit card on the company account, in my name and everything happens as in your case. Better put a paper trail on the cash by depositing in the bank. Sometimes the HMRC might become a whacko and start drilling. THe paper trail is for that untoward occurence, if that happens.

Comment: How about changing banks to one that doesn't charge for you depositing cash at a branch.

Answer (score 6):

Let me do the math. .6% * (not large) = really tiny. Since "not large" = "small" , etc.

I suggest that even a small chance that you need to explain this to anyone in the future is a sign to avoid the risk. Yes, there are times that it's illegal. A real estate office may not deposit escrow funds into anything but a segregated escrow account. 
In your case, even if legal, it messes up 'the books' and can cost you more in grief than the 'tiny amount' saves you in cash.

Answer (score -1):

buy a cashiers check with the cash (a CRT will be nec if over 10 K) and deposit the cashiers check